# Remotely connecting to a Hyper-V hosted VM's console

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, remote-desktop

I've just managed to successfully move an aging beige box into a Hyper-V virtual machine. We used to use the beige box by walking over and sitting at the computer itself, but we can't do that so easily when its inside the Hyper-V system.

Is there a way please to access the VM's console from a workstation running XP Pro?

Please note that its an obscure OS running inside the VM, so installing a VNC or similar service inside the VM is not an option.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V Manager is available as part of the Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) in all flavors of Windows 6.x including Vista, Win7, Server 2008, and Server 2008 R2.  Unfortunately, it is not supported on Windows XP.

Does your user account have administrative rights to the Hyper-V host machine?  You certainly could RDP into the host and run Hyper-V Manager there.

Of course, this won't work if you are trying to provide access to this legacy system for non-privileged users.  If that's the case, VirtualBox might be a better fit than Hyper-V because it can provide RDP access to the console of each virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

With XP I think you're going to be out of luck, the [Remote Server Admin Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FF6E897-23CE-4A36-B7FC-D52065DE9960&displaylang=en) allow you to do this for Vista and Windows7. What you might be able to do is RDP into a Win7\W2K8 box and access the console Remotely from there, it's not likely to perform particularly well though.